# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Xubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I know this is asked a lot, but I couldn't find an answer that fit my situation. I had no pointers in my code and yet I ran into this problem. My program is meant to factor a number, although I haven't been able to test run the program. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce, So actually xubuntu.
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int wholeNum;
int newNum;
int divider = 2;
int b;
int holderNum;
int remainNum;
bool stopper[wholeNum];



cin >> wholeNum;

while (wholeNum != divider){

    holderNum = wholeNum / divider;
    remainNum = wholeNum % divider;

    if (remainNum == 0){

        if (stopper[divider] != true || stopper[holderNum] != true){
            cout << divider << " * " << holderNum << endl;
        }   
        stopper[divider] = true;
        stopper[holderNum] = true;      
    }

divider ++;
}

return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is happening, as I'm not using pointers and it compiled perfectly. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can't expect someone to find bugs in your code when you haven't even spent the effort to execute it yourself. "forgive any programming mistakes I made because I haven't been able to test run the program"

Comment: @fallenidol I couldn't execute because of the error. I was just saying that the program in itself may not have been built properly. I wanted the answers to focus on the main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the array:

```
bool stopper[wholeNum];
```

`wholeNum` is still undefined.  So array `stopper[]` is of undefined size.  You need to first input the value of `wholeNum` (using `cin`) and then declare the `stopper[]` array.  So basically, something like this:

```
int wholeNum;
//Other lines of your code

cin>>wholeNum;
bool stopper[wholeNum]; //---> Here value of wholeNum is defined.
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/nRHu7k) is the successfully complied program.

Hope this helps!